# PointerWheelChanged Event UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a GridView with enabled VerticalScroll. In MainPage.xaml.cs I intercepted the ScrollView's PointerWheelChanged Event.

In this PointerWheelChanged event, can you know whether the wheel scrolls up or down?

The code.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txbNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <GridView x:Name="TestGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Background="#FF44AF0D">
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
        <GridViewItem Content="item"/>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TestGrid.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerWheelChangedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(OnPointerWheelChanged), true);
    }
    int number = 0;
    private void OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txbNumber.Text = number.ToString();
        number += 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Examine the [`MouseWheelDelta`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpointproperties#Windows_UI_Input_PointerPointProperties_MouseWheelDelta) property of the `PointerRoutedEventArgs` as follows:

```
private void WindowsPage_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var delta = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
}
```

Its value (int) indicates the direction the wheel has moved.

From the docs:

> A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward (away from the user) or tilted to the right; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward (toward the user) or tilted to the

Comment: Fixed the Link.

Comment: How do I differentiate a pinch zoom from a slide translate though on a Touchpad? Even running GestureRecognizer.ProcessMouseWheelEvent on the current point doesn't give a Scale only an X/Y.